# MY Ubuntu 12.04 is not booting after using testdisk data recovery?? it gives error loading drmk? please help

Tags: 12.04, wubi

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 lts. during upgrading i lost all my data then i tried to recover it using test disk data recovery...but  after shutdown when i restart there comes black screen having following commands on it...

```
Loading DRMK V8.00...
DRMK version 8.00
COMMAND.COM Build 37-Jul 28,2008
DRMK KERNEL Build 15 -Aug 8,2008
Copyright(c) 2006-2008 Dell Inc. All rights reserved.
C:\>-
```

I don't know what to do now.. kindly help me if anyone know... as soon as possible...
I have tried many commands but it gives error i-e `Bad command or File name`